# Type class constraints in type signature inside an instance when the type is a free variable

Tags: haskell

How can I add type class constraints in type signature inside an instance when the type is a free variable in Haskell. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

class Pair a where
    pair :: a -> b -> (a, b)

instance Pair Int where
    pair :: (Show a) => a -> b -> (a, b)
    pair a b = (a, b)
```

works, 'a' is a bound type variable whereas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

class Pair a where
    pair :: a -> b -> (a, b)

instance Pair Int where
    pair :: (Show b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
    pair a b = (a, b)
```

gives this error:

```
source_file.hs:8:13:
    No instance for (Show b)
    Possible fix:
      add (Show b) to the context of
        the type signature for pair :: Int -> b -> (Int, b)
    When checking that: forall a b. Show b => a -> b -> (a, b)
      is more polymorphic than: forall b. Int -> b -> (Int, b)
    When checking that instance signature for ‘pair’
      is more general than its signature in the class
      Instance sig: forall a b. Show b => a -> b -> (a, b)
         Class sig: forall b. Int -> b -> (Int, b)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Pair Int’
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible. You are basically trying to change the Type Signature of your show Function. In your first example the Show constraint on a is used as a constraint for the Instance, in the second example pairs type gets changed to `Show b => a -> b -> (a, b)`

Comment: In the first case, it is unifying the types `(Show x) => x -> b -> (x, b)` and `Int -> b -> (Int, b)` which unify when `x ~ Int`. In this case the `Show x` constraint is entirely redundant, which is why it is permitted to be there at all - it is erased when the type is simplified. You have not 'added' a constraint to anything in any sense. In the second case, the types `Show b => x -> b -> (x, b)` and `Int -> b -> (Int, b)` simply do not unify; setting `x ~ Int` as before still leaves the `Show b` constraint which doesn't match (which is exactly what the compiler tells you).

Comment: I stumbled here looking for the syntax for adding constraints into instance declarations, it's like this  `instance SomeOtherClass a => ClassBeingImplemented a where`

Answer (score 4):

At the conceptual-intuitive level, the `class Pair` is a promise to the consumer. It says "there is this function `pair`, which will work for this type `a` and any other type `b`". Anybody who sees the class can use the function with any type `b`.

But your instance is trying to say "I'll implement this function `pair`, but only for `b`s which have a `Show` instance". Well, this is not a complete implementation of the class: the class promises to work for any `b`, but the instance works only for *some* `b`s.

Comment: Hmm _is_ that the promise? Take `instance Show a => Pair a where ...`. Bare `a` in the instance head is a promise function `pair` will work for any type `a` -- except the constraint says it works only for _some_ `a`s. So why is that different to constraining `b` inside the body?

Comment: Because `b` is not in the class head. The promise of class `Pair` is NOT to "work for any type `a`" (and note that I didn't say that in my answer). The promise is to work only for those types `a` for which there is an instance of the class. That's what it means for `a` to be in the class head. But `b` is not in the class head, which means that the promise is different regarding `b`.

Comment: In general, the class definition is the promise. Whatever is present in the class definition, that is what is promised. If the class definition had `pair :: Show b => a -> b -> (a, b)`, then the promise would be to "work for any `b` that has a `Show` instance". The class definition is the promise, and all instance declarations are obligated to keep it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The type of `pair` is `forall a b. Pair a => a -> b -> (a, b)`.

Where `a = Int`, this specializes to `forall b. Int -> b -> (Int, b)`.

In the first example, your type declaration `forall a b. Show a => a -> b -> (a, b)` specializes to `forall b. Show Int => Int -> b -> (Int, b)`, and then further reduces to `forall b. Int -> b -> (Int, b)`. (The `Show` constraint just gets dropped because it is redundant; you're "constraining" a concrete type, which is meaningless.) This is the correct type.

In the second example, you're trying to define an instance where `pair` has the type `forall b. Show b => Int -> b -> (Int, b)`, which doesn't work because that's a different type.